# Add custom project template to Visual Studio Preview for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I'm trying to add a custom project template to Visual Studio Preview for Mac, but can't find the right place or folder to add it.

Any idea where I should but the template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **Visual Studio Preview for Mac** the project templates can be placed in `~/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/7.0/LocalInstall/Addins`

**Visual Studio Preview for Mac** is forked from Xamarin Studio, which in turn is based on MonoDevelop. Creating 'project templates' for MonoDevelop is done with **Add-ins**, the instructions for which are outlined in the [Documentation](http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/creating-a-simple-add-in/).

I did a quick experiment by copying a project template (Add-in) from Xamarin Studio and dropping it in the above location and it appeared in the 'New Project' dialog.

Comment: for some reason this doesnt seem to work with the regular visual studio 2019 for mac. The folder was there under application support .. I copied my template zipfile in, then uncompressed it there (so both the zip and the dir are there, wasnt sure which form was required), restarted visual studio .. but I can't find my project template.

Comment: I can see this file directory on mac ~/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio after directory /7.0/LocalInstall/Addins couldn't see